# Simple search on Firebase database with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new with Firebase and for the past two days, I've been trying to figure out how to perform a simple search on my db without any success.

[image]

And I want to perform search on all the channels children. For example I want to search if there is a channel named `Klx0N4pxsBHGVkhYuY0`. I try the

```
queryEqual(toValue: "Klx0N4pxsBHGVkhYuY0")
```

but no luck.

Thank you so much in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is observe that path and if there is no data, the `snapshot.value` will be nil.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels").child("Klx0N4pxsBHGVkhYuY0")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let value = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {

        // There is data, so it exists

        print(value)

    } else {

        // There is no data, so it doesn't exist
    }
})
```

Comment: your answer it works too. thank you for your time n' help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to "search if there is a channel named Klx0N4pxsBHGVkhYuY0", you can do this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.hasChild("Klx0N4pxsBHGVkhYuY0") {
         // yes, it is
    } else {
         // no, it isn't
    }
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Vlad, you make my day. Hope you have a good day too.

Comment: @kstefanou glad to hear. Have a nice day:)

Comment: This is not a practical way of doing this! You are downloading the whole database then searching through all that data, which is expensive in time, internet data, and computing power. With my answer, you are only downloading the data if it is there, which will save time and computing power. You need to consider which is the correct way of doing this. @kstefanou

Comment: @TristanBeaton yeah. It depends on situation. Maybe he will anyway download all channels. So. If topic starter thinks, that your answer in his situation is more correct, he can re-accept it. But in this case also uparrow my. Cuz it's still correct. Thanks

Comment: @TristanBeaton you are right, but as I said I'm new on firebase so I don't fully understand the difference but you are right your answer is best for my situation. I accept your answer. thank you both of you.

Comment: @kstefanou you can uparrow my answer, cuz it also works